# Querying Hive table with Spark DataFrames causes ClassNotFoundException in yarn-client mode

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to run a basic "Hello world" type example using DataFrames with Hive in yarn-client mode. My code is:

```
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext("yarn-client", "Test app"))
HiveContext sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc.sc());
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM my_table").count();
```

This works fine in local mode, but when I run it in yarn-client mode I get this exception on the driver:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.TableDesc

I've confirmed that the missing class is on the driver classpath by using this:

```
try {
    Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.TableDesc");
    System.out.println("On classpath");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Not found on classpath");
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Update: I don't get any errors running in local or yarn-cluster modes. This issue only happens in yarn-client mode.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to provide the hive client libraries along with your code. It's probably easiest to use allinone, shading or fatjars in your build (maven, gradle or SBT)

Comment: What do you mean "provide the hive client libraries"? Those libraries are on the classpath of the driver application. Is there something else that I need to do?

Comment: they need to be staged for the workers, not only for the driver, because worker run on different machines

Comment: The error that I'm getting is happening on the driver. Also, from the Spark documentation: "These jars only need to be present on the driver". http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables

Answer (score 0):

While running you can pass the jars like

```
 Spark-submit .....    --jar /usr/hdp/hive/lib/hive-client.jar
```

Also export hive home , hadoop home and spark home

Comment: Is it possible to get this to work without running it in spark-submit? I thought that was only required for yarn-cluster mode?